# Not Able To assign click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html code. In my page there are many  tag which have class='posta' but what i want assign onclick event only to which have post attribute.

```
<ul class="posts_li">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="posta" post="status">Post</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="posta" post="act">Act</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="posta" post="event">Event</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="posta" post="news">Create News</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My Jquery Code for assigning an event is here

```
$(".posta").click(function(){
            alert("here");
            if($(this).attr("post")){
                alert($(this).attr("post"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use attribute selectors `[propertyname]` to select only nodes that have that property.

```
$(".posta[post]").click(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: @user1511547 using this syntax in a CSS selector won't work in all browsers, but jQuery uses it's own selector engine http://www.myinkblog.com/sizzle-a-look-at-jquerys-new-css-selector-engine/ thats implemented in pure javascript for older browsers, ensuring support for this feature.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".posta[post]").click(....);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LmrPR/

Comment: Beat me too it! I would just do .on('click', function () { }); Otherwise this works!

Answer (score 1):

Then use `[attribute=value]` in the selector:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gqRmC/)

```
$('.posts_li').on('click', '.posta[post]', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("post"));
    return false;
});​
```

Additionally, you can avoid placing an event handler for each item by delegating them to the parent. In this example, I placed a single handler on the `<ul>` for all child elements using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (jQuery 1.7+). For older jQuery (1.4.2+), [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is also available.

Comment: Consider mentioning the jQuery version, since `.on()` ain't available to all :)

Comment: @Zuul everyone should be using the latest anyways. why stick to using an older version?

Comment: I have many projects in production with code designed specifically for the version of jQuery that existed at the time they were developed. Specific code often to circumvent known bugs or to "add" a missing functionality that currently is already available. However, if I was to replace them, my headache would increase dramatically and I would not be able to put this comment **;)** *(this is only one reason as to why developers may still hang out to old versions)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the css/jquery attribute selector:

```
$(".posta[post]").click(......... your code here)
```

Here's the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wHvkF/

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish it using:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/af8pb/) example. <sup>the last from the list doesn't alert</sup>

```
$(".posta[post]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("here");
});
```

*Works since version 1.0 of jQuery.*